Why are self-signed SSL certs less secure than Certificate Authority signed ones?
An SSL certificate can either be self-signed, or signed by a certificate authority. Modern browsers will only trust a site that provides an authority signed certificate.
A user can get an authority signed certificate for their domain if the user proves to the authority that it owns the domain name (ex: via ability to manipulate the domain’s DNS records).
This is done to establish some sort of security — they prove to the browser that the site the browser is visiting is actually controlled by the legitimate owner of the domain.
But I don’t understand how this proof of ownership actually increases security.
Isn’t it pretty much implied that a domain owner owns the underlying site it points to? And even if it doesn’t, why does that matter?
Is the idea that a hacker could breach the DNS records and point a well-known domain to their malicious server? I can see how this would protect end users. But if a hacker has that level of access, they can just generate a new SSL cert to plop onto their server anyways.
I keep reading that this helps against bad actors spoofing well-known sites with something like "go0gle.com". But if this attacker owns "go0gle.com", they can get a CA to issue them a cert for this copycat domain name and appear as "trustworthy" in the eyes of the browser.

No, certificates prevent man-in-the-middle attacks on the TLS encryption. The hacker doesn't need to "breach DNS records" for that, spoofing DNS or rerouting IP (particularly in a local network) is much simpler than taking over the authoritative DNS server for the entire internet (that a CA would contact to check ownership).

"they can just generate a new SSL cert to plop onto their server anyways" - that requires confusing (or coercing) the CA, but yes this is possible. Which is why certificate transparency helps to detect and expose those actors.

Yup, I was missing that whole slice of the possibility of IP redirection. This makes so much more sense now. Thank you very much.

TLS is a client-server protocol, so from the point-of-view of the client there are several things to check, but I'll pile them into two bins. 1) Verify the signature and that it chains to a trusted anchor, check that it's within the validity period, and that it contains the required fields, and then 2) for HTTPS, perform the hostname check. The hostname check verifies that the hostname the client tried to connect to matches a name in the Subject Alternative Name extension of the certificate. It is the hostname check which is meant to protect you from a go0gle.com with a valid cert.

As stated in above comments, the client will check "root CA certificate" of the certificate chain that is presented to itself against its own Trusted root CA certificates.  There is a built-in OS Trusted Root Store though the administrator can add new trusted Root CA certificates later to this store. If the presented certificate's root CA does not exist in this store, then the client does not believe that it is secure even the CN matches exactly the company name. As far as I know, formal documents are also required from the applicants before the well-known CA issues a company TLS certificate
